# keeping control with the same handle between form loads

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, handle

I have a form with a control I draw on with another application. The other application loads too slow to start it each time I show my window.

So I load the secondary application in advance. I use a control handle as argument, telling the application which handle to draw on.

This works fine the first time. When I close my dialog (clicking the ok button, setting the dialog result to ok) and open it again, the control handle changed.

How can I keep my control handle the same between two loads of the dialog?

```
public partial class ListForm : Form
{

FilterDialog filterDialog;

public ListForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     filterDialog = new FilterDialog(); //this is where I load my second form, which I draw in
}
```

the Dialog I draw in

```
public FilterDialog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string applicationlocation = @"...";
    //set the argument
    string hexvalue = btnImage.Handle.ToInt32().ToString("X8");
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "0x" + hexvalue;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = applicationlocation;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
}

private void FilterDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.filter != string.Empty)
       txtFilter.Text = filter;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some sample code? The question is a bit ambiguous

Comment: added some sample code

Comment: Clearly you do **not** want the window to close, that will destroy the control handle.  You'll have to hide it instead, use Hide().

Comment: even if i hide, the handle changes. I catch the closing even, cancel it and call Hide() instead, but still get another handle for my control (button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code *seems* to work:

```
class CustomHandleForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        base.DestroyHandle();
    }

    protected override void DestroyHandle() { }        
}
```

Tested with:

```
Form f = new CustomHandleForm();
f.Show();
var h1 = f.Handle;
f.Hide();
f.Show();
var h2 = f.Handle;

Trace.Assert(h1 == h2);
```

Comment: Just overriding DestroyHandle() does indeed seem to do the trick! Thanks!